# Unable to Handle huge HTTP request

Tags: mysql, linux, jsp, http, tomcat

I am using Apache Tomcat Version 8, It contains 5-8 web application developed in J2EE with some frameworks i.e. Spring, Struts, most of them are developed in Servlet also there is database connection with them on same system. These application are running on Linux OS with Java 7.

Every time when I am restarting Apache tomcat server its able to handle certain amount of http request after that its unable to handle the request, every new request taking too much time and webpage connection time out.

I have tried many ways to solve this issue but failed. Also I have increase connection limits in Apache Tomcat as well as at OS level but no solution.

If anyone has any idea please guide me to solve this issue.

> OR

Is there any other web server which can solve my issue?

Comment: Does the work that timed out ever finish?

Comment: No, its take too much time else timed out

Comment: Did the work finish on the server even after the client timed out?

Comment: lets suppose 1000 http session is running on application and next another session is reqeusting the resourre over http then this new connecting will take too much time to execute(will work) or it will be timed out(with out work)

Comment: Unfinished threads will cause this behavior. Attach with a debugger.

Comment: It sounds like the problem is in your application code.  Have you attempted to determine which method is taking such a long time?